# Native Google maps not working

Tags: codenameone

I've tried the Native Google maps and this how it looks on device , only google logo but no map is shown
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt7NF.png)

Answer (score 2):

This is due to using invalid API key. You need to check that you follow every steps in generating the key correctly.

- Create your app android keystore in the project property.
- Generate a SHA1 key
- Copy the key and your app identifier and paste them in your google console, separate the 2 with a semicolon.
- Create both android and iOS keys.
- Add the 2 in your build hint as follows:

  ```
  android.xapplication=<meta-data     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"     android:value="Your_Key_Inside_these_double_quotes"/>
  android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/><uses-feature         android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"         android:required="true"/>

  ios.add_libs=libc++.dylib;libicucore.dylib;libz.dylib;CoreData.framework;CoreText.framework;GLKit.framework;ImageIO.framework;SystemConfiguration.framework
  ios.glAppDelegateHeader=#import "GoogleMaps.h
  ios.afterFinishLaunching=[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"Your_Key_Inside_these_double_quotes"];
  ```

Also you need to turn on your Google Map APIs, this could actually be the problem...

- visit https://console.developers.google.com
- Click the sidemenu and select **API manager**
- Enable all the Google Maps APIs applicable to you.

Comment: I did all the steps and still same problem

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue.  The logcat seems to indicate everything is working, too.  No error messages, just "Blocking creation...", "Google Play services package version...", "Finished blocking..."

Comment: In the end it was an API key issue, I had loaded my signature for my keystore, but of course it didn't recognize the signature from a debug build.